# why Kali Linux does not recognize the battery charge?

Tags: kali-linux, battery

this is my first post as a Linux user. The system is working wonderfully. But I'm having a problem with the recognition of my battery. It only walks with the charger plugged in and continues without recognizing the charge. My PC is relatively modern, I have all the power management packages installed, I don't know what else to do. suggestions?

Comment: Have you try any other distribution? Did you get the same problem with them?

Comment: Replace the battery. Clean the battery contacts